# Query not being inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql

I need help figuring out why this query isn't working.

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'DB.php';

$message = "Error";

if (!empty($_POST['statement1'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test2 (first, middle, last, statement1) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['first']}','{$_SESSION['middle']}','{$_SESSION['last']}', :statement1 )";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':statement1', $_POST['statement1']);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header("Location: Login.php");
    } else {
        echo $message;
    }
}

?>
```

I tested this previously w/ another database where I just inserted the statement1 value and it worked fine. Now that I have added the session variables, the code does not complete the insertion. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you ONLY BINDING the last variable

Comment: do all session and post arrays contain values? connecting with the same apI? too many unknowns

Comment: `else:
            Echo $message;` doesn't help you here; check for the real errors.

Comment: Check `$stmt->errorInfo()` and escape your $_SESSION data before useing in a query (why not bind them too?). finally make real $variables because `bindParam` takes references so use a variable like `$statement1` for it.

Comment: Where is your error checking `prepare` and `execute` can both fail

Comment: Does this database contain a table called `test2`

Comment: Sidenote: You only need `bindParam` if you want to execute the statment not only once, else use just `?` instead of `:arg` and then `execute([$arg])`

Comment: Have you checked your ERROR LOGS

Comment: ok no response. You can take it up with the answer below, I'm out.

Comment: Yes, all sessions and post arrays contain values and they are correct. When I put :statement1 in quotes, the query worked. The users name was inserted but of course it inserted the last value in the database as :statement1 and I need the user input to be there.

Comment: $errors = $stmt->errorInfo(); will give you readable error info about the query. doing a try catch around the prepare to execute will through a pdo exception if something went wrong that isn't sql but a pdo error. Also it's best practice to split the sql query into multiple lines for readability and to help stop one type of sql injection attack. Also you should be binding your session vars to the statement like you are with post as pdo will then handle types and some sanitation for you.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you may prefer to do so:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'DB.php';

$message = "Error";

if (
    !isset(
        $_SESSION,
        $_SESSION['first'],
        $_SESSION['middle'],
        $_SESSION['last']
    ) ||
    empty($_SESSION['first']) ||
    empty($_SESSION['middle']) ||
    empty($_SESSION['last'])
) {
    echo 'No valid session...'.PHP_EOL;
} elseif (
    isset($_POST['statement1']) &&
    !empty($_POST['statement1'])
) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO test2 (
            first,
            middle,
            last,
            statement1
        ) VALUES (
            :first,
            :middle,
            :last,
            :statement1
        )'
    );
    $stmt->bindParam(':first', $_SESSION['first']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':middle', $_SESSION['middle']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last', $_SESSION['last']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':statement1', $_SESSION['statement1']);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header("Location: Login.php");
    } else {
        echo $message;
    }
}

?>
```

Assuming you will have `$_SESSION['first']`, `$_SESSION['middle']`, `$_SESSION['last']` and `$_POST['statement1']` variables, and assuming `$conn` will be created thanks to the page `DB.php`

### Session issue

If this code prints `No valid session...`, you have an issue with `$_SESSION` variables:

- no existing `first`, `middle` or `last` index within `$_SESSION` array
- one of these index match an existing value and has an empty value

If so, you may want to try after executing this code:

```
<?php

// be sure session_start() is used before to edit $_SESSION variable
session_start();

$_SESSION['first'] = 'Foo';
$_SESSION['middle'] = 'Bar';
$_SESSION['last'] = 'Foobar';
```

and refresh! :) (do not include the opening PHP tags, it's only for specifying to other users that this code is PHP)

You could insert this code right after `session_start()` or before the closing `?>` PHP tag.

### Database query issue

If it is printing your default `Error` message, then it may be that you have something wrong with your query: you may are trying to insert a value which the type do not match the one from your database. In order to figure out what is going on, you may want to use:

```
<?php

var_dump($conn->errorInfo());
```

after your query execution.

Check for errors also.

### References

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

---

I hope this will help you!

Comment: how do you know the session arrays are posts? `'{$_SESSION['first']}','{$_SESSION['middle']}','{$_SESSION['last']}'` - assuming? I hope you're right about this.

Comment: `session_start();` so why include that if there's no session arrays? *lol*

Comment: sorry, my bad, I changed back my code from POST to SESSION variables...

Comment: the OP hasn't responded to any comments or to your answer. This isn't good in many respects. We ask for clarification in comments but they either don't know what we're talking about, or ignoring us or left the question. I had left the question and leaving it again ;-) I really hope they haven't chased you down a possible deep rabbit hole here.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Also, I did answer your question Fred -ii-. I am also working on something else &  didn't expect such speedy responses.

Comment: I hope this will help you, at least, debugging your issue; I tried to explain as much as possible in order to do so. Please let me know if it helped :)

Comment: @Alexandre my bad on the edit I made duh lol I used the wrong API, sorry about that. But error reporting should be included in there. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, by editing before your second edit, sorry, you insert them back? I touch nothing

Comment: @Alexandre It was my fault. I had the links for error reporting and mysql_error where it should have been http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - Edit: I made the new changes with the links.

Comment: thank you for inserting them back, it's nice from you :)